# Removing HTML from a jQuery .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Parse.com backend and am rendering its data, ultimately, with a jQuery append, like this:

```
$(".albums").append(
    "<div class='col-xs-6 col-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-3'><div class='flip animated fadeInDown' style='-webkit-animation-delay:" + i * 0.1 + "s'><div class='card'><div class='album front' style='background-image:url(" + bigImg + ")'><img class='artwork' src='" + artwork + "' alt='" + collectionName + "' /></div><div class='album back' style='background-image:url(" + back + ")'><img class='artwork' src='" + back + "' alt='" + collectionName + "' /></div></div></div></div>");
```

It's a `for` loop hence the need for the various HTML elements and their classes. I know it's an appalling, shameful way to do it (and I believe it's causing a memory leak).

My questions are: How can I remove as much of the HTML from this append statement as possible? Should I be using a templating language?

Comment: jQuery/JavaScript won't cause a memory leak because it has [automatic garbage collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).

Comment: A templating engine might be overkill if you're only doing this html generation. However if you are generating a lot of html via javascript, then it would be helpful.

Comment: Are you appending to the DOM in a loop? Try collecting all your HTML together and then using a single append.

Comment: @VLS Yes, I'm fetching some album artwork URLs and displaying the images in a grid. So there's an append for each image. How would I use a single append?

Comment: Outside of a loop, declare an empty string. Then use that string to concatenate all your HTML output from the loop. After the loop is finished, append that string to the DOM.

Comment: Actually, don't create an empty string, create an Array.  Then push all your strings on the array and .join('\n') them at the end as you append to the DOM.

Comment: don't append inside the loop, make your html string (one way or another),  when ready wrap it in something & append it at once

Comment: @MikeEdwards string concatenation is (allegedly) faster, but either method will perform better than DOM injections.

Comment: @VLS interesting.  Intuitively knowing strings are immutable you'd think += would be an expensive operation, but if the data says otherwise the guys building the engines must have done something clever under the hood :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think you might want to use a templating language you can start by building your own, super simple, template.

Simply replace

```
"some string stuff " + someValue + " some more stuff"

// instead

var myTemplate = "some string stuff {someValue} some more stuff";
// now render
myTemplate.replace('{someValue}', someValue);
```

It's easy to go further, and wrap this in a function to "render" that takes an object as an argument and iterates over keys.  Done carefully this will provide you a subset of the functionality provided by "off-the-shelf" templating libraries so you can always cut-over later.

This will allow you to predefine your "template" and render using the data input provided.  The next question is *where do you want to define your template*.  Generally you would relocate it to a separate free-standing file that the designers would have access to, perhaps in a "templates" directory.  But then you have to load it.

If you have lots of templates, some libraries would allow you to pack them together in one file, load the file, then ask the library for a specific template by name.  Your designers would then control this file and the CSS that goes with it.  If you have a lot of this, then the architectural overhead starts to make sense.

Whether you want to go down that road really depends on your specific circumstances and the structure of your project team.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This seems like a nice tidy solution that can be built upon, and your answer helped me understand the issue.

Comment: ...interesting side-note -- once implemented, the page that runs this JS now is consuming ~119% of CPU according to Chrome's Task Manager. It was high before, (like 80%, hence my point in the question about memory leak), but seems to have really jumped now. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm.  that is interesting.  How often are you calling this?  High CPU does not necessarily indicate a memory leak.  If you are seeing that much of a jump than this code must be a hot-spot.  I figured since you are pulling data from the backend that this would only be called occasionally - are you generating a lot of re-renders after the initial load?  You may want to debounce or throttle a render function.

Comment: No, the only re-renders occur if there are more than 12 results and the user elects to load them, at which point 12 more are appended. Otherwise it's only new queries that would fire it again (or a page reload). I will try and clean up the rest of the code / do a reduced test case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Handlebar](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for this sort of thing.

This would be the template

```
<script id="albumsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class='col-xs-6 col-6 col-sm-3 col-lg-3'>
        <div class='flip animated fadeInDown' style='-webkit-animation-delay:{{delay}}s'>
        <div class='card'>
            <div class='album front' style='background-image:url({{bigImg}})'>
                 <img class='artwork' src='" + artwork + "' alt='{{collectionName}}' />
            </div>
            <div class='album back' style='background-image:url({{back}})'>
                 <img class='artwork' src='" + back + "' alt='{{collectionName}}' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

And then you would use it like this:

```
var source   = $("#albumsTemplate").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var html    = template({delay:i*0.1,
                        bigImg:bigImg,
                        collectionName:collectionName,
                        back:back});
$(".albums").append(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `html()` to the call should do it. That'll return the html inside of `.albums`. To get everything including `.albums` you do `$('.albums').append(...).parent().html()`.

Comment: Where? How? This is not an answer yet.